# Is checking for normality and linearity in this way correct?

Tags: regression, normality-assumption, linearity

Testing normality using a significance test is a little bit useless especially when you have a large sample size

So, recently I found a way to test normality by running a fake regression using simulated data from a chi-square distribution. This simulation is an illustration.

```
set.seed(417)

data <- data.frame(a=sample(1:7,100,replace=T),
                  b=sample(1:7,100,replace=T),
                  c=sample(1:7,100,replace=T))
#generating a random chisquare values

rfake <- rchisq(nrow(data), 7)

#running regression using this fake data

fit <- lm(rfake~.,data)

#checking  normality 

hist(resid(fit))

#checking  linearity

car::qqPlot(fit)

#checking  homogeneity

plot(scale(fitted(fit)),scale(resid(fit)))
abline(h = 0)
abline(v=0)
```

Is this way correct?

If not, is there a more practical way to do it?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "appropriate"?  Also, I don't see any actual statistical tests in your code--only graphical displays.  What "tests" are you referring to?

Comment: i mean that if you want to check normality in any way other than tests like shapiro ,, is this way correct ,, to run regression on random data and check it

Comment: Why do you need to run a regression to see how is your data distributed

Comment: here we supposed to run anova for example , i choose to diagnose the residuals instead of each individual data column

Comment: Well, if your objective is to test normality of error terms in a regression model, then you certainly should base that test on residuals.  But--depending on the model and how you fit it--it's usually not quite correct to apply a normality test that assumes the data are a simple random sample (and therefore independent). Many such tests have been devised and checked, so why not just ask what it an appropriate test for your situation rather than asking what might be wrong with your *ad hoc* approach?